# how to increase worker count (parallel jobs) in zeromq

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeromq

I am VERY new to zeromq and I have been looking at the streamer model: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/streamer.html for my use case (python bindings). It works fine, as in, I see that the task is getting distributed (I call an external C++ binary in python), but I see at most only 6 parallel jobs, whatever I do with the Context()

So, my burning question is how do I increase the worker count (i.e the number of parallel jobs) in this streamer model? I looked at the docs and could not find a solution for this.

Comment: Are you creating more than 6 workers? Can you show us your code?

Comment: the code is just a copy paste of the link I have posted (exactly the same, no change). I think I found a solution  - I basically need to increase the number of workers. Interestingly, each worker seems to be capable of taking 6 jobs.. I wonder why or how it decides this.